# External Table for Parquet or Avro data format throws error

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

i created an external table to fetch Parquet data from ADLS which throws below error.

```
Query execution has resulted in error (0x80131500): Partial query failure: 0x80131500 (message: 'Input parquet file is ill-formed and cannot be processed: 'not a Parquet file (size too small)'.: ', details: 'Source: Kusto.Common.Svc [0]Kusto.Common.Svc.Exceptions.IngestionSourceParquetReaderException: Input parquet file is ill-formed and cannot be processed: 'not a Parquet file (size too small)'. Timestamp=2020-05-07T11:22:42.0340199Z
```

**Folder structure at ADLS:-**
logs / {AppId}/ 2020 / 05 / 07

**External Table definition :**

```
.create external table ExTParquet (AppId:string,UserId:string,Email:string,RoleName:string,Operation:string,EntityId:string,EntityType:string,EntityName:string,TargetTitle:string,Params:string,EventProcessedUtcTime:datetime,PartitionId:string,EventEnqueuedUtcTime:datetime) 
kind=blob
partition by 
   AppId,
   bin(EventProcessedUtcTime,1d)
dataformat=parquet
( 
   h@'https://streamoutalds2.blob.core.windows.net/stream-api-raw-parquet/logs;secret_key'
)
with 
(
   folder = "ExternalTables"   
)
```

**Note : if i provide full file path and remove source directory partitioning from External Table definition , it works well.**
But i need to ready data for all the files within directory and not just one.

Any help is much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue being worked out. You can open a support ticket (Azure Data Explorer). The team will also post here an update when issue is resolved.

[EDIT] the issue should have been resolved.

Comment: Thank You , i have opened support ticket.